# Preventing the map labels to overlap when adding custom markers with labels in React Map GL

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, react-map-gl, maplibre-gl

I'm using `react-map-gl` with `maplibre-gl` to render a map on a React application. I'm simply trying to add a custom marker with a label next to it.

The problem is that they overlap with the actual map labels and symbols (see picture):
[image]

The marker is stored in an atom state and is added to the map programmatically after the user clicks on the search places suggestion. This is how I initialize the app:

```js
<MapView
  id="map"
  initialViewState={{
    longitude: 146.6639,
    latitude: -42.6685,
    zoom: 11,
  }}
  mapStyle={`https://api.maptiler.com/maps/outdoor-v2/style.json?key=...`}
  style={{ flex: 1 }}
>
  {marker && (
    <Marker
      latitude={marker.latitude}
      longitude={marker.longitude}
      anchor="bottom"
    >
      <MarkerCustom label={marker.label} />
    </Marker>
  )}
</MapView>;
```

I've tried to offset and set the anchoring, even though it prevents the marker from completely overlapping, it's still quite bad to look at it. I wonder if there's a way to completely hide the main label when the marker overlaps on it?